# css work in chrome but not in ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Below css work in Chrome and safari but every time when I use it with IE, scroll bar will automatically appear like this. [ie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iud46.png). It should be like this [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62diQ.png)

```css
.area {
  height: 98px;
  width: 98px;
  margin: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9n38d4F.png" height=100 width=100>
</div>
```

Comment: height and width should be in quotations and you can set overflow to visible to show the content and prevent the scroll bars

Comment: which version of IE, which doctype, loaded from a server or from a file directory ? Pleasse clarify, your code actually works as expected in IE11